hit an invalid opcode while deploying
i cant deploy my code on ganache and this is my eror:
hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

and because of openzeppelin i should use solc ^0.8.20
and i have checked migration for 1000 times but it was okay
is there anybody know what should i do????
i did it with this code but got that error:
truffle migrate

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you want to continue using truffle/ganache, then you have to change the solidity version to 0.8.19.
I suggest however to get rid of truffle/ganache since they are deprecated. Try hardhat or forge.
